# XML Parsing Error - Extra content at end of document

Tags: xml-parsing, sap-data-services

I have been trying to parse this xml response from a service and I keep getting a parsing error. I am working with BODS and its very sensitive to xml structure.

XML response as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <GetMapDataResponsexmlns="http://insbridge.net/wsi/Connector/SoftData">
        <GetMapDataResult>
            <ibdoc gen_date="1/27/2016 11:31 AM" timespan="0.000000" site_location="whlibqa" xmlns="">
                <dataresults lob="20" env_def="sr_int">
                    <program parent_id="675" id="0" ver="1">
                        <m i="5" r="4" n="Get EL Increased Limits" l="false">
                            <d p="28">
                                <v>0</v>
                                <v>0</v>
                                <v>100000</v>
                                <v>100000</v>
                                <v>500000</v>
                                <v>1</v>
                                <v>1</v>
                                <v>1</v>
                                <q>1</q>
                                <q>03/01/2003</q>
                                <q>12/31/2012</q>
                                <q>FL</q>
                            </d>
                            <d p="29">
                                <v>0.008</v>
                                <v>50</v>
                                <v>500000</v>
                                <v>500000</v>
                                <v>500000</v>
                                <v>1</v>
                                <v>0</v>
                                <v>0</v>
                                <q>2</q>
                                <q>03/01/2003</q>
                                <q>12/31/2012</q>
                                <q>FL</q>
                            </d>
                        </m>
                    </program>
                </dataresults>
            </ibdoc>
        </GetMapDataResult>
    </GetMapDataResponse>
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What's the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: Maybe it is because your xml is malformed "<GetMapDataResponsexmlns=" . There is a space missing. Beside that you could be more specific regarding your tool setup and error message.

Comment: thanks Jah, you are correct, the issue was the absence of space before xmlns.. I have fixed this issue.